# How to Navigate to new Page after response is received about submission in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

its last of the code which store all user to googlesheet after submitting the form
but it not navigating to new page
to
class MainPage which is in login.dart file
and this below code is in main.dart file

```
      RaisedButton(


        color: Colors.blue, 

          textColor: Colors.white,

          onPressed: () {
            _submitForm();
            navigateToMainPage(context);
          },
          child: Text('Submit Feedback'),
        ),
```

Comment: show _submitForm and navigateToMainPage

Comment: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                _submitForm();
                navigateToMainPage(context);
              },
              child: Text('Submit Feedback'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigateToMainPage(BuildContext context) {}
}   this is bottom part of code

Comment: how to do it Autocrab?